# Not showing confidence interval with prop.test

Tags: r

I am trying to run the prop.test in R to find the 90% confidence interval for this matrix but I only end up with this as the result:

```
X-squared = 37.762, df = 2, p-value = 6.312e-09
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2    prop 3 
0.3712121 0.3426791 0.5750000
```

Here is the matrix:

```
 [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   98  110  161
[2,]  264  321  280
```

The code:

```
prop.test(nausea,no_nausea, p = NULL, alternative = "two.sided",
          correct = TRUE)
```

Assume nausea is the first row and no_nausea is the second row

Comment: it is only returned with a one or two group test, see the documentation for `conf.level` argument and `conf.int` in the "Value" section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. You have to define the desired `conf.level` inside of `prop.test()` first. `prop.test()` returns a list that includes an element called `conf.int`. You can access that list element with the usual `$` syntax.

```
result <- prop.test(nausea,no_nausea, p = NULL, alternative = "two.sided",
                  correct = TRUE, conf.level = 0.9)
    
result$conf.int
```

Comment: If you type ?prop.test you'll see the documentation for the function. @rawr mentioned it in a comment above, but conf.int will be NULL when certain conditions are not met. Here's what the documenation says about the conf.int value:


"a confidence interval for the true proportion if there is one group, or for the difference in proportions if there are 2 groups and p is not given, or NULL otherwise. In the cases where it is not NULL, the returned confidence interval has an asymptotic confidence level as specified by conf.level, and is appropriate to the specified alternative hypothesis."